# Dynamic table using AJAX and JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, jdbc-odbc

I am having a table `tbIndividual` say having 4 columns : `ID`, `I_Name`, `FName` and `LName` of individuals.

Now I want to search for individuals in my web application in such a way that as I press'A' individuals whose name starts with 'A' all comes down in a tabular form below in my page and if I press next button say 'B' then only individuals matching the criteria remains on the page and all other are gone.

I am working in JSP and new learner to AJAX.

But not getting the desired output.Please help

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>SEARCH DATABASE</title>
    <script>
    function showuser(str)
    {
        var xreq;
        if(str=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("showtext").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xreq=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        else
        {
            xreq=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xreq.onreadystatechange=function ()
        {
            if((xreq.readyState==4) && (xreq.status==200))
            {
                document.getElementById("showtext").innerHTML=xreq.responseText;
            }
        }

        xreq.open("get","getdata.jsp?q="+str,"true");
        xreq.send();
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showuser(this.value)">  
</form>
<br />
<div id="showtext">THE DATA IS</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `getuser.jsp` is as follow that make the connection and print results in table.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>MY DATA</title>
</head>
<body>
<%!Connection con; %>
<%!PreparedStatement s; %>
<%!ResultSet rs; %>

<% 
String name=request.getParameter("txt1");
out.println(name);

try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SharedCryptography", "fyp", "fyp");

    String sql="select * from tbIndividual where I_NAME like ?";    
    s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    s.setString(1, name + "%");
    rs=s.executeQuery();
}
catch(Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
%>

<div id="dtl_table"><table border='3' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2' width="400px">
<tr bgcolor="66FF00">

<th>ID</th>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>FIRSTNAME</th>
<th>LASTNAME</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<% while(rs.next())
{ %>
    <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
<% } %>
</tr>
</table></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Am not getting any errors But not getting results too.

EDIT : `individualdetails.jsp`

```
<body>
<%!Connection con; %>
<%!PreparedStatement s; %>
<%!ResultSet rs; %>
<% String idperson=request.getParameter("personid");

 try{
     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SharedCryptography", "fyp", "fyp");

     String sql="select * from tbIndividual where I_ID=?";    
     s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     s.setString(1,idperson);
     rs=s.executeQuery();
}
catch(Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
</body>
```

Comment: Your SQL query statement searches for the exact string. It should be like `select * from tbIndividual where I_NAME like '"+name+"%'"`. You will want to make use of prepared statements to mitigate SQL attacks.

Comment: @Tiny I did that too.But still no results

Comment: You're using a prepared statement. I did not notice it. The query should now be like `select * from tbIndividual where I_NAME like ?` and use the `setString()` method to replace the placeholder `?` like `s.setString(1, name + "%");`.

Comment: @Tiny that is just to avoid sql injection.I will do that also.But why am not getting table on entering the keys from keyboard

Comment: The query statement requires a placeholder `?` and a corresponding setter method for it to work because you're using a prepared statement. It is essential to have this select query as commented previously.

Comment: @Tiny Is this what your are saying ?i edited in post.But its still not working

Comment: Interchange the order, `s.setString(1, name + "%");` should be below this line `s = con.prepareStatement(sql);`.

Comment: @Tiny Ohh yeah,sorry i ran my code with it above.It stills didnt work..Please help

Comment: The AJAX request goes to `getdata.jsp` with a querystring parameter `q` which implies the search string (the page you're showing is however, `getuser.jsp`). Are you sure the request is going right to the intentional page? If it goes to the right page then, change `String name=request.getParameter("txt1");` to `String name=request.getParameter("q");`

Comment: @Tiny thanx ,Now the last question.The records are coming in one line.How to make them come in seperate lines?

Comment: I did not understand but remove all HTML from `getdata.jsp` except `<table>` (or `<div>`). They are not required to be shown as an AJAX response. The AJAX response should only be the HTML table you're populating from the database.

Comment: @Tiny I removed those all,And it works fine now.But what if i had to create a hyperlink on each of the first column value of my table.How to modify <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td> so that it become a hyperlink and refer to some other page.?

Comment: `<td> <a href="Your location" name="aName" id="aId" ...> <%=rs.getString(1)%> </a> </td>`.

Comment: Are you getting the value of `personid` correctly through `request.getParameter("personid");`? What is the value of `idperson`? Try printing it out.

Comment: @Tiny yeah that problem is resolved now.What if i want to put a add button with all searched individuals and send those persons a notification sort off which i had decided to add to form a group

Comment: A similar way you added a link, `<a>` in an HTML table. This may need a separate/different question where besides me others can also see as it is completely new and I myself cannot envision it correctly now :)

Answer (score 0):

See as per my knowledge query what you have written is perfect even its protected from sql attack.

in your jsp page you have used

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showuser(this.value)">
```

since request.getParameter() uses the attribute name instead of id.
so at server side its value is coming as null and query is fired against null% so it might not be coming.

so replace above code as below

`<input type="text" id="txt1" name="tx1" onkeyup="showuser(this.value)"/>` 
and try now
let me know the update.

Comment: Even attributing `name="tx1"` to `<input type="text">` won't work because it is a GET request.

Comment: @user1763507 Yeah,That problem has been removed by comment of Tiny.Now my problem is what if i had to create a hyperlink on each of the first column value of my table.How to modify <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td> so that it become a hyperlink and refer to some other page.?

Comment: `request.getParameter("tx1")` refers an element with the `name` attribute `txt1` (not `id` which is referenced by a client script like JavaScript) and is available, if the form is submitted with a POST request. In case of a GET request, it is required to be appended as a query-string parameter to the URL as you're doing in the question, @user3462609

Comment: @Tiny Oh ok,And how to approach if now i created the hyperlinks, i want to open a different webpage showing details of a individual depending on which hyperlink we had opened?

Comment: Pass some values like `id` as a query string to that anchor tag like `<td> <a href="individualDetails.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString(1)%>" name="aName" id="aId" ...> <%=rs.getString(1)%> </a> </td>` and using this value (`id` in your database, may be a primary key) to show the details of different individuals, @user3462609

Comment: @Tiny How to use this passed value in another jsp page ?

Comment: `request.getParameter("id");` (assuming you're passing `id` as a query string parameter like `<a href="individualDetails.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString(1)%>"`...), @user3462609

Comment: @Tiny Its giving an exception now .Is their any probelem with this code ?<% while(rs.next())
    { %>
    
    <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
    <td><a href="individualdetails.jsp?personid=<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></a></td>
    <% } %>

Comment: What is the exception? The code looks fine, at a glance, @user3462609

Comment: @Tiny data not found exception.See my edited post for individualdetails.jsp

Comment: `java.sql.SQLException: No data found` occurs, when a column is attempted to read multiple times. Assign the value of `rs.getString(1)` to some variable and use that variable instead (`rs.getString(1)` is being read multiple times) , @user3462609